# wp mu bbpress - How to avoid profile url redirect to home issue?

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I have wp mu(3.6) and bbpress 2.4 installed as plugin.

The following url http://www.mydomain.local/forums/users/51cdf2a4630ff/ make redirect to site home and not show user profile page.

**I've tried to deactivate all plugins (except bbpress) but the issue isn't fixed.**

This is the .htaccess (but any other page works perfectly):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**Does someone have any ideas?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a working solution on this post http://zzlatev.com/bbpress-404-header-in-users-profiles/